# DatabaseRestart

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, mysqladmin

I have strange problem, we are using circulation replication, between 2 different network with 5.6.25 and 5.6.22 version of MySQL and RAM is 64GB with 45GB `innodb_buffer_pool`

Master Server is running MySQL 5.6.25

Replication path is:

server A 5.6.25 (Flash Drive) -> server B 5.6.22 (Normal HDD) -> Server C 5.6.25 (Flash Drive) -> server A 5.6.25 (Flash Drive).

In testing phase all are well but after deploying application to server A 5.6.25, MySQL of Server A is frequently restart and at that time RAM consumption is 88%.

Error log show nothing.

After MySQL restart, error log show:

```
2015-07-21 15:35:57 80155 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost.localdomain' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'NM123_binlog.010144', position 11117338
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Warning] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Warning] Slave SQL: If a crash happens this configuration does not guarantee that the relay log info will be consistent, Error_code: 0
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'NM_binlog.010144' at position 11117338, relay log '/mysql_log/relaylog/master-relay-bin.025738' position: 286
2015-07-21 15:40:39 80155 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'replica@192.268.200.123:3310',replication started in log 'NM_binlog.010144' at position 11117338
```